# What is wrong with new Action(() => someCombobox.Text = "x" )

Tags: c#, lambda

When I write in my code

```
Action(() => someCombobox.Text = "x" )
```

I get this error:

> Delegate '`System.Action<object>`' does not take 0 arguments

Why?

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1149243/196526). I just want to understand why this error occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 2.0 generics: How to create an Action object with zero parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149243/c-sharp-2-0-generics-how-to-create-an-action-object-with-zero-parameters)

Comment: @DanSeaver: not exactly a duplicate since the answer is different in .net 3.5 and up I believe. ie the answers below would not have been valid on that question (or at the very least weren't given).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to create a `System.Action` delegate which has no parameters and does not return a value, simply change your code to this, removing the `new Action([body])`:

```
Action newAction = () => someCombobox.Text = "x";
```

This is because the lambda expression will return a new parameterless `System.Action` delegate for you. EDIT: as noted by [Aliostad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002593/what-is-wrong-with-new-action-somecombobox-text-x/9002647#comment11283715_9002647), `() => someCombobox.Text = "x"` will return either a lambda expression or an `Action`, depending on the type of the variable you are assigning it to.

EDIT: as Darin says, if you wish it to accept an argument then you need to pass that in when creating the lambda expression.

Comment: Or potentially: `(() => someCombobox.Text = "x")();` (which would seem a little pointless).

Comment: @MatthewAbbott good point I assumed the assignment, i have edited my answer now

Comment: virtual -1. `This is because the lambda expression will return a new parameterless System.Action delegate` This is **technically wrong**. It can return a lambda expression or an action depending on the variable you have defined.

Comment: @JamesShuttler Updated comment :-)

Comment: @Aliostad this is true, I made the assumption that the result of the expression was being assigned to an `Action` delegate

Answer (score 8):

You do not have to pass that as a constructor parameter:

```
 Action a = () => someCombobox.Text = "x";
```

All you have to do is to declare an action and then use lambda expression to create it.

Alternatively you can pass the string to the action:

```
  Action<string> a = (s) => someCombobox.Text = s;
  a("your string here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is the same as in the related question you are linking to: .NET 2.0 only has a definition for an Action delegate that takes a parameter.

The parameterless Action delegate was added in .NET 3.5, and requires a reference to System.Core.