# Action in rewriting code from .NET 4 to .NET 2 C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 2.0 generics: How to create an Action object with zero parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149243/c-sharp-2-0-generics-how-to-create-an-action-object-with-zero-parameters)

I use code to delegate method like this:

> this.Invoke((Action)(() => importProcessExited()));

And I'm getting an error:

> Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires 1 type arguments.

How this line of code supposed to be in .NET 2?

Comment: It will have to be rewritten as an anonymous delegate invocation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(v=vs.80).aspx Or back to a standard named delegate type.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a new delegate without type arguments.

```
delegate void Action();
```